# How to write to Delta Lake using "zstd" compression codec in AWS Glue?

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, pyspark, aws-glue, delta-lake

I have AWS Glue job. It is using "Glue 4.0 - Spark 3.3, Scala 2, Python 3" version.

It reads individual parquet files and write to Delta Lake. I am using `"write.parquet.compression-codec": "snappy"` which is from the code generated by AWS Glue Visual ETL.

Now I am hoping to change to use Zstandard `"write.parquet.compression-codec": "zstd"` instead.

Here is my new code:

```py
import sys
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job

args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ["JOB_NAME"])
sc = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session
job = Job(glueContext)
job.init(args["JOB_NAME"], args)

S3bucket_node1 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_options(
    format_options={},
    connection_type="s3",
    format="parquet",
    connection_options={
        "paths": [
            "s3://my-bucket/data/raw-parquet/motor/"
        ],
        "recurse": True,
    },
    transformation_ctx="S3bucket_node1",
)

additional_options = {
    "path": "s3://my-bucket/data/new-zstd-delta-tables/motor/", # <- An empty new folder
    "write.parquet.compression-codec": "zstd", # <- Changed to zstd
    "mergeSchema": "true",
}
sink_to_delta_lake_node3_df = S3bucket_node1.toDF()
sink_to_delta_lake_node3_df.write.format("delta").options(**additional_options).mode(
    "overwrite"
).save()

job.commit()
```

However, the final parquet files generated in Delta Lake still looks like `part-00107-85b2560f-81a4-4d05-8d09-5df143685dbf.c000.snappy.parquet`. Note `snappy` in the name.

I also verified the file content is actually using "snappy" compression codec by

```py
import pyarrow.parquet as pq

parquet_file_path = "part-00107-85b2560f-81a4-4d05-8d09-5df143685dbf.c000.snappy.parquet"
print(pq.ParquetFile(parquet_file_path).metadata.row_group(0).column(0).compression)
# It prints "SNAPPY"
```

How to write to Delta Lake using "zstd" compression codec in AWS Glue correctly? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `compression` option instead ([doc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-parquet.html)). For example:

```
spark.range(100).write.format("delta")\
  .option("compression", "zstd").mode("overwrite").save("zstd.delta")
```

will give you the desired output (tested on Databricks & local Spark):

```
# ls zstd.delta
_delta_log/
part-00000-b7078370-6b8f-4632-8071-8ee2dbc61194-c000.zstd.parquet
part-00001-3201e316-1cc7-4f78-9945-f7b4b21922b0-c000.zstd.parquet
part-00002-d25fb0ed-bf7d-468f-bd98-df480c2acabd-c000.zstd.parquet
part-00003-b9e60fb8-2d7a-4e4f-981c-a4c9314c9b41-c000.zstd.parquet
part-00004-224f9282-930b-4a89-ba08-2c4b752781dd-c000.zstd.parquet
part-00005-4671308a-3e6a-4cba-83ad-bb6e7f404d68-c000.zstd.parquet
part-00006-2b08bbf9-7ece-4ccd-828b-88713fe226f9-c000.zstd.parquet
part-00007-53fc0ebb-29b1-496c-bcce-f2994ec04226-c000.zstd.parquet
part-00008-f0cf609d-d1c4-4805-8586-dd6e9481cc9b-c000.zstd.parquet
part-00009-a918c5c8-77ea-4f6d-b559-d36740e5a3bb-c000.zstd.parquet
part-00010-4a47e50d-dfdc-4f7f-826a-7e273a2fd404-c000.zstd.parquet
part-00011-95625e5a-7130-4f45-bf6c-bc721fe7561b-c000.zstd.parquet
```

Alternatively, you can set it globally:

```
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.parquet.compression.codec", "zstd")
```

Comment: Thanks Alex, both methods work for me! For curiosity, I also tried `.option("spark.sql.parquet.compression.codec", "zstd")` which does not work.

Comment: yes, it's a bit of a difference between names in `.option` and `spark.conf`. The former is having very few options, so it's okay to use simpler names, but the latter has dozens of options, so we need to have some hierarchical structure.

Comment: Hi @Alex Ott, I have a follow up question setting compression level is at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77204328/how-to-set-zstd-compression-level-in-aws-glue-job which may help future people too 